# "Base table or view not found" error in docker container

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I have Laravel app with mysql db. I'm trying to run it in docker using this docker-compose.yml:

```
load_balancer:
image: tutum/haproxy
links:
    - web
ports:
    - "80:80"

cache:
    image: redis

web:
    image: andrewmclagan/nginx-hhvm
    links:
        - db
        - cache
    volumes: 
        - ./:/var/www
    environment:
        - APP_ENV=local
        - DB_DATABASE=regappbase
        - DB_PASSWORD=Q1w2e3r4t5
        - DB_HOST=db
        - VIRTUAL_HOST=laravel.local

db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Q1w2e3r4t5
        MYSQL_DATABASE: regappbase
```

On my host database has three tables:

- migrations
- password_resets
- users

When I run the app and try refer to database, I have an error like this:

> QueryException in Connection.php line 715: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: Table 'regappbase.users' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from users where email=(e-mail@ghhjghj77))

How can I create database regappbase? I don't need to store data, only schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I spend two days trying to change variables, or use data-only-container, or mount sql-scritps.
But the decision was to make from running web-container:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation for the mysql image (hub.docker.com). There is a directory which you can mount your .SQL scripts into, on container start mysql will loop through and execute each file in this dir. Use this to build up your DB schema

"Initializing a fresh instance
When a container is started for the first time, a new database mysql will be initialized with the provided configuration variables. Furthermore, it will execute files with extensions .sh and .sql that are found in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. You can easily populate your mysql services by mounting a SQL dump into that directory and provide custom images with contributed data"